# Select data with certain pattern (href) following in sql server 2005 db

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with a html content column
What i needed is to select all the present href content from it like

```
select 'href="MyFirstPAge.aspx" <table><tr><td> href="http://www.test.com/2009/05/aa-bb.html" </td></tr></table> href="MySecondPage.aspx"' as content
```

i needed the result as

1. MyFirstPage.aspx
2. http://www.test.com/2009/05/aa-bb.html
3. href="MySecondPage.aspx"

Any idea what should i do?

I needed the distinct list from all of the rows.

Have tried with a function

```
create function dbo.GetLinks (@t nvarchar(max))
    returns @Links table (link nvarchar(max))
as
begin
    declare @strtpos int 
    SET @strtpos = PATINDEX('%href="http%.aspx"%', @t)
    declare @endpos int 
    SET @endpos = 0
    declare @lnk nvarchar(max)
    while @strtpos > 0
    begin
        select  @endpos = PATINDEX('%.aspx"%', @t)+ 5
          , @lnk = substring(@t ,@strtpos, @endpos - @strtpos +1) -- here is the error 
          , @t= RIGHT (@t, len(@t) - @endpos)
          , @strtpos = PATINDEX('%href="http%.aspx"%', @t)
        insert @Links values(@lnk )
    end 
    return
end
go
```

But getting error
Msg 536, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function.

Sample data is

> ```
> <a shape="rect" href="http://www.qwewqe.fda.gov/wqewqe/pdf8/wewe.pdf"
> ```
>
> target="_blank">System rket.
>
> been calling for
>        rocess,in 2010,
>
> ```
>  target="_blank"> changes. </p><p style="text-align: justify">The  <a shape="rect" href="fghfghfgh.aspx" target="_blank">
>  substantially equivalent.</a> </p><p style="text-align: justify">Per th </p><p style="text-align: justify">market. </p>
>  <p style="text-align: justify">The <a shape="rect" href="asdd.aspx" target="_blank">sub.</a> </p><p style="text-align:
> ```
>
> justify">
>        Perhaps
>
> t of a one-in-eight revision  Critics de 
>        5 We If 
>        sdfsdf asd
>          sasdasdasd

Comment: Please add a sample input data and expected output.

Comment: I have added a it in question For
'href="MyFirstPAge.aspx"  href="http://www.test.com/2009/05/aa-bb.html" href="MySecondPage.aspx"'

Row 1 = MyFirstPage.aspx
Row 2 = http://www.test.com/2009/05/aa-bb.html 
Row 3 = href="MySecondPage.aspx"

Actually editor has weird the text


My out put should be

Comment: Take `select  @endpos = PATINDEX('%.aspx"%', @t)+ 5` out of the `SELECT` statement and calculate it first. After that, you may use value in the next statement.

Comment: mceda not able to do it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this enough?

```
declare @t nvarchar(max), @strtPos1 int, @strtPos2 int, @strtPos3 int
set @t='href="MyFirstPAge.aspx" href="http://www.test.com/2009/05/aa-bb.html" href="MySecondPage.aspx"'

SET @strtPos1 = PATINDEX('%.aspx"%', @t)
SET @strtPos2 = PATINDEX('%.html"%', @t)
SET @strtPos3 = PATINDEX('%href="http%.aspx"%', @t)

select substring(@t, 1, @strtPos1+4) union
select substring(@t, @strtPos3, (@strtPos2+4)-@strtPos3) union
select substring(@t, @strtPos2+7, LEN(@t))
```

As function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetLinks (@t NVARCHAR(MAX))
    RETURNS @Links TABLE (link NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @strtPos1 INT, @strtPos2 INT, @strtPos3 INT
    SELECT @strtPos1 = PATINDEX('%.aspx"%', @t), @strtPos2 = PATINDEX('%.html"%', @t), @strtPos3 = PATINDEX('%href="http%.aspx"%', @t)

    INSERT INTO @Links SELECT SUBSTRING(@t, 1, @strtPos1+4)
    INSERT INTO @Links SELECT SUBSTRING(@t, @strtPos3, (@strtPos2+4)-@strtPos3)
    INSERT INTO @Links SELECT SUBSTRING(@t, @strtPos2+7, LEN(@t))

    RETURN
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks techdo
How can i incorporate it into above funtion so that i can retrieve it in a reult set

Comment: As i menitoed if there are other html character like table td tr tags  your funtion doesn't work

Comment: Please add a sample input.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your function as follows:

```
create function [dbo].[GetLinks] (@t nvarchar(max))
    returns @Links table (link nvarchar(max))
as
begin
    declare @strtpos int
    set @strtpos=100
    declare @endpos int 
    declare @lnk nvarchar(max)
    while @strtpos > 6
    begin
        set @strtpos = PATINDEX('%href="%', @t)+6
        if @strtpos>6 begin
            set @endpos = CHARINDEX ('"',@t,@strtpos+1)
            if @endpos>0 begin
                set @lnk = substring(@t ,@strtpos, @endpos - @strtpos)
                set @t= RIGHT (@t, len(@t) - @endpos)

                insert @Links values(@lnk )
            end
        end
    end 

    return
end
```

After trying the following example:

```
select * from dbo.GetLinks('hello world href="MyFirstPAge.aspx" <table><tr><td> href="http://www.test.com/2009/05/aa-bb.html" </td></tr></table> href="MySecondPage.aspx"') as links
```

It returns:

```
MyFirstPAge.aspx
http://www.test.com/2009/05/aa-bb.html
MySecondPage.aspx
```

Comment: Thanks atheer.I will rewrite it.At the moment i have done my problem solution in .net[after fetching the result i have put regex with pattern and find all the data]

Comment: Ok good luck, by the way you can also use SQL Server 2008 services RegEx function mdq.RegexMatches but you need setup first read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Comment: how can i get links with .pdf extension only?